# UWP How can i get the click event of notification from notification history?

Tags: c#, uwp

How can i get the click event of notification from notification history

Using

> toastNotification.Activated += ToastNotification_Activated;
>
> but it's not working when I click on notification popup from history

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to  override `OnActivated` in App.Xaml.cs,  and you will get `ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs` in `OnActivated` method like the follow. For more please refer [**Send a local toast notification**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast)

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the root frame
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // TODO: Initialize root frame just like in OnLaunched

    // Handle toast activation
    if (e is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)
    {
        var toastActivationArgs = e as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;

        // Parse the query string (using QueryString.NET)
        QueryString args = QueryString.Parse(toastActivationArgs.Argument);

        // See what action is being requested 
        switch (args["action"])
        {
            // Open the image
            case "viewImage":

                // The URL retrieved from the toast args
                string imageUrl = args["imageUrl"];

                // If we're already viewing that image, do nothing
                if (rootFrame.Content is ImagePage && (rootFrame.Content as ImagePage).ImageUrl.Equals(imageUrl))
                    break;

                // Otherwise navigate to view it
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ImagePage), imageUrl);
                break;


            // Open the conversation
            case "viewConversation":

                // The conversation ID retrieved from the toast args
                int conversationId = int.Parse(args["conversationId"]);

                // If we're already viewing that conversation, do nothing
                if (rootFrame.Content is ConversationPage && (rootFrame.Content as ConversationPage).ConversationId == conversationId)
                    break;

                // Otherwise navigate to view it
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ConversationPage), conversationId);
                break;
        }

        // If we're loading the app for the first time, place the main page on
        // the back stack so that user can go back after they've been
        // navigated to the specific page
        if (rootFrame.BackStack.Count == 0)
            rootFrame.BackStack.Add(new PageStackEntry(typeof(MainPage), null, null));
    }

    // TODO: Handle other types of activation

    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```